# In teamcity MSbuild.exe incremental clean causing issues

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

So I have 2 projects that are copies of each other in Teamcity. One is QA and the other is stage. The only difference between the 2 is that they pull from 2 different branches in the repo and they use 2 different pubxml's. The pubxml's are supposedly the same except for the publish url.

For the publish step we use a command line build step that calls the MSBuild.exe and uses a pubxml to publish the files. In stage in the build log we see there is an Incremental Clean section where several of our dll's are being deleted from the checkout directory. They are then understandably not being copied to the deployment server. In QA this isn't happening, in fact there is no incremental clean section at all. The files are just copied over and no problems.

Can anyone help explain what is happening? What causes this incremental clean step to occur during the MSBuild.exe and how can I stop it?